# When printing cases is it possible to NOT print the notes on the case?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

When using the built-in print functionality on a Case, is it possible to avoid printing the notes attached to the case?

If it's not possible I'll be creating a SSRS report to do it, but I'd rather just use what's already there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do it by embedding a hidden HTML web resource in the page that hides elements when it is a print preview page.

Example code that would turn a field to a different color:

```html
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <SCRIPT type=text/javascript>
            if (top.location.href.indexOf("/print/print.aspx") != -1) {
                //Do your own DOM manipulation here to hide sections
                top.frames[0].document.getElementById('caseorigincode_d').firstChild.style.color = '#0000FF';

            }
        </SCRIPT>
        <META charset=utf-8>
    </HEAD>

    <BODY contentEditable=true>
        <FONT size=2 face="Tahoma, Verdana, Arial">
            Testing…
        </FONT>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

This method comes via: [http://www.crmsoftwareblog.com/2011/08/printing-in-crm-2011](http://www.crmsoftwareblog.com/2011/08/printing-in-crm-2011/)/

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I used top.frames[0].document.getElementById('notescontrol_d').style.display = "none"; to hide the notes div. It still shows the section header that says Notes, but that's ok for me.

Comment: @JasonLattimer, you are in every place someone asks about Dynamics :D . +1 Good answer.

Answer (score 1):

if you put:

```
<field name>_c
```

it is the header/label

`<field name>_d`

it is the data value

in you case just put:

```
{
   top.frames[0].document.getElementById('notescontrol_c').style.display = "none"
   top.frames[0].document.getElementById('notescontrol_d').style.display = "none"
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that took care of it.